# Unable to refresh access_token - google calendar api

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

Greetings my fellow developers
I am working on a project where client needs to connect Google calendar with the project.
I am using GAPI for connecting Google calendar with my application.
Here is what I am doing:

step 1:

```
let config = {
    apiKey: [API_KEY],
    clientId: [CLIENT_ID],
    access_type: 'offline',
    discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'],
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'
}
gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    gapi.client.init(config).then(() => {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(true);
    });
});
```

step 2:

```
Promise.resolve(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()).then(response => {
    store access_token, id_token, login_hint
}).then(() => {
    run_different_axios_requests_to_google_calendar();
});
```

or if I already have access tokens:

```
run_different_axios_requests_to_google_calendar();
```

Till this point it runs perfectly!

Problem comes when access token is expired, and read documentation and I found out that if you run `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance(). grantOfflineAccess()` instead of `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()` you get `refresh_token` along with `access_token`, `id_token`, `login_hint`, but I don't get a response, in fact my promise shows that `This app isn't verified`, and i need refresh token for when access_token expires so that I can get new token, without having to ask user to signin again (via promise). I am not sure what I am doing wrong here! any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [complete documentation](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/12/using-new-js-library-to-unlock-power-of.html) from Google that let you to use the new JS library to unlock the power of Google Apps. It explained thoroughly the step by step procedure from authentication to using GAPI libraries like Calendar API.

Comment: hello jess!
i have tried your mentioned documentation, it is working, with this there is no need to save access_token on my end (for future calls), but it solves this issue but then it shows another problem, i want to be able to get calendar events from loggedin user, which means, it should be able to make calls on basis of which ever user is logged in, what this is doing is it asks for permission once, and then use that permission response to make further calls, if new user logs in, calls are still to previous user not new one! i hope i have explained my point well,